# Installation error on lubuntu

Tags: system-installation, startup

When i try to install either Lubuntu or Ubuntu MATE, I see an ACPI error about the power button event failed to enable.

The ACPI error I'm not too worried about, I saw others had similar errors and they were told to ignore those errors.

My main worry is when I choose any option that goes to the logo/bootup, the PC  freezes. I do have Windows 8.1 installed which I'm going to overwrite, plus a different PC with Windows 10. Here is a picture of the [frozen screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwAsJ.jpg).

The PC is an [Acer Aspire One, model ZA3](https://us.answers.acer.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/328/session/L3RpbWUvMTU4NTE2MDk5Ni9nZW4vMTU4NTE2MDk5Ni9zaWQvZlVQZkgxQmNlbFRNT3ZyNm5hNTVzeEx4NThyb3NFTW9yWHdWYUR0bkgySWxjdGVNZExoZG05WVlRVF81cGtLX19pRUklN0VYME1ROTJMUWZzTkgxOTVfaVF4bjVBZHdfSU94WElTaHZVJTdFOVpLUWNoQkJtQlhEaGZMZyUyMSUyMQ%3D%3D); I believe it has 2 GB of RAM and a 250 GB HDD.

Lubuntu is ver. 18.04
Ubuntu-MATE is ver. 18.10
And dor your last question, i dont know

Comment: 1) Which release number of Lubuntu and Ubuntu MATE did you install? 2) In your BIOS/Firmware settings of the PC, is the drive controller set to SATA, AHCI,, RAID, or something else? Please click [edit] and clarify by revising the question. The question is your channel to us, and should contain all facts about an issue; Add Comment is our one-way channel to you

Comment: This is now very old, but mentions a boot parameter which you might try. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AspireOne/AO751h as it seems like some sort of video issue.

Comment: Any release 18.10 release is dead, as is its upgrade path (which was to 19.04 now gone as 19.04 is also EOL), and those releases being EOL (*end-of-life*) are also off-topic here as unsupported. Which Lubuntu 18.04 LTS did you try?  18.04? 18.04.1? or later?  Did you verify ISO after download? (https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/1/1.1/retrieving_the_image.html) and verify your write to install media? ("*Check disk for defects*")  The ACPI message is like a warning (not error) but we can't know if you aren't specific.  Did you try `nomodeset`?  (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu/AdvancedMethods)

Comment: @oldfred thank you for your help. it worked after adding `intel_idle.max_cstate=3` to the boot line.